# Overlay or Indicator on the Webpage Pagination

Tags: css

Can you please assist me with adding an indicator or Overlay on a Wordpress Website.
The website is https://www.thearcadestick.com

I need for the pagination at the bottom of the page to identify what current page the user is on.

This is the Custom CSS code I tried adding to the Wordpress site, but it didn't work:

```
span.page-numbers.current {
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
```

I did adjust the values to try different colors.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding **!important** tag, I tried on your site it works.

```
span.page-numbers.current {
    color: #cb2027 !important;
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

[image]